# Actionbar not rendering using nbandroid

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

Cannot get the Actionbar to load.  It works using Eclipse and Android Studio but I prefer to work in Netbeans if at all possible.  New to Android development

MainActivity.java

```
package action.bar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbarmenu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

actionbarmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->


<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/contacts"

      android:title="Private Contacts"
    />
    <!-- android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_person" -->


</menu>
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="action.bar"
      android:versionCode="15"
      android:versionName="15.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: "I prefer to work in Netbeans" - This is not a good idea.

Comment: Eclipse does seem to support the Android platform much better..